# How to drag, drop & swap pictureboxes in tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

How to give `TableLayoutPanel` functionality to drag drop controls between cells and swap those controls?

Comment: The idea is troublesome, the click events go to the controls you click on, not the TLP.  Very hard to get the drag started unless you put strong limitations on the kind of controls in the panel.  No button, textbox, etcetera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be feasible if the TLP is fixed size in rows and columns and not autosizing (because an empty row or column may disappear). And it may help to fill each cell with a `Panel` as parent of your controls, so you only have to swap the content of panels. Managing controls in the TLP cells themselves is a bit more complex. Come to think of it, when using a TLP in such a restricted way you might as well draw a grid of Panel controls yourself.